# AutoCompleteTextview not giving the result if I am entering middle character of string

Tags: android, autocomplete

My String Array is like this : ["l1","l2","l3","l4"].
If I am typing l than it is giving me suggested result but if I am entering '1' than it is not giving me any result.
So please give me suggestion how to solve this issue.

Comment: You need to check whole string if it contain any word that user searched or typed.

Comment: You need to customize the search, basically to do it manually

Comment: I can do the customize the thing but isn;t there any thing to do search any character any position?

Comment: can you write your code how are you getting data .. :)